# What is a "shadow game" from Gone in 60 Seconds?

Tags: plot-explanation, gone-in-60-seconds

In the planning scene in Gone in 60 Seconds, Kip suggests playing a "shadow game", which Memphis quickly dismisses. However no amount of googling seems to be able to tell me what that actually is.

> **KIP:** *You spread it out ... you move around... So's they can't touch you... so's they don't know... **Shadow games and shit ...***
>
> **MEMPHIS:** **"Shadow games?"**
>
> **KIP:** *Shadow games ...*

Answer (score 6):

In context he seems to be referring to using misdirection to throw the police off their scent, presumably boosting cars they don't need and moving from area to area in order to force the police to try to work out their (heavily disguised) plan.

For example, If one wanted to steal ten Lamborghini cars to order, perhaps stealing three the first night along with six (*unneeded*) Mercedes cars would confuse law enforcement:

> "You got maybe a better plan?" Donny Astricky asked, completely skeptical.
>   "Yeah!" Kip said. "You spread it out. You move around. Shadow games and shit."
>   "Right," Memphis said, dismissing the comment. "Go on, Otto."
>   "Since we're on a truncated timetable, we take a day to shop it, a day to prep, and—"
>   "Hey," Kip interrupted. "Didn't you hear what I said?"
>   "Yes. We heard," Memphis said. "Shadow games. But what you have to understand, Kip, is that if you play shadow games, by the next night, the heat is on to you. With a one-night boost, by the time the first cars are reported stolen, your ship's set sail."
>   Kip and the others nodded begrudgingly. It made sense. Memphis nodded to Otto, who continued his analysis. - <sub><sup>[Gone in 60 Seconds: Movie Tie-in](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1853554.Gone_in_60_Seconds_Movie_Tie_In)</sup></sub>

Comment: No.  Just...  No.  You wouldn't boost six Mercedes cars that you have no way of getting rid of.  Boosting **one** car can get you busted and sent to prison for plenty of time.  You wouldn't risk that to get 3 out of 10 needed Lambos.  What are you gonna do with these 6 extra cars that are near impossible to steal to begin with?

Comment: @johnnybones - Chuck them in the canal or just drive them out onto waste land or into the nearest multi-story car park. They're the distraction. You don't need to do anything *clever* with them. The whole point is that you retain the element of surprise. On day two,  the police will be dividing their time looking for stolen mercs.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - Impossible to steal? [I beg to differ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=be5xBRgb0xo)

Comment: **Near** impossible to steal.  They needed specific traceable keys to do it, which is what got them caught.  And Memphis was supposedly one of the best.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - I bow to your more extensive knowledge of car thievery. They would probably have been stealing *'Insert name of expensive car that's notoriously easy to steal'* instead.

Comment: And let's not forget, those 2 clowns got busted.  So, they didn't really "steal" it.  Plus, it was pretty obvious that something out of the ordinary was going on, like keys left in plain sight.  You can't hotwire that car that quickly, if at all.

Answer (score 2):

The term "Shadow Games" is associated with the term "Cloak & Dagger", and is usually used in connection to some sort of spy or espionage-type activity.  Misdirection is a key component, and (as any James Bond fan could tell you) it may involve making one action *appear* to be a different action.

In this context, Kip is suggesting stealing one car from one area of town, another car from another area or surrounding town, etc..., not on the same night.  Spread it out.  Don't let anyone recognize there's a pattern.  Case out the cars (which they do for one Mercedes, actually), make careful decisions on what the easiest targets are.

Memphis, on the other hand, suggests the polar opposite; get them all on the same night, as quickly as possible, before information can be exchanged by law enforcement.  Grab and go, and let your driving skills get you out of trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Shadow games isn't stealing extra unneeded cars. It simply means to spread out the time of stealing. Steal 25 tonight...25 tomorrow night. Or skip a few days if you have time to do so (which they didn't at the moment). Prime example: remember at the beginning of the movie when the warehouse got raided. Kip and his crew had only collected 13 cars and the order had already been placed for the cars two weeks ahead. Kip was stretching out the boost...playing shadow games...But being hella slow at it haha..